# Iterar y generar múltiples tablas usando la función table

Tags: r

Tengo dos data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("categoria 1", "categoria 2", "categoria 1", "categoria 1", "categoria 2"), 
                  y = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")) 

df2 <- mutate(df1, 
              x = case_when(df1$x == "categoria 1" ~ 1L, df1$x == "categoria 2" ~ 2L), 
              y = case_when(df1$y == "A" ~ 1L, df1$y == "B" ~ 2L))
```

Quiero asegurar no omitir ningún valor de df1 con el mutate - case_when en df2.

Una forma sería:

```
table(df1$x, df2$x)
table(df1$y, df2$y)
```

y ver que los valores fuera de la diagonal sean todos cero. Para no repetir el mismo código múltiples veces, pensé en:

```
for(i in colnames(df1)){
   table(df1[, i], df2[, i])
}
```

Pero parece que la estructura df[ , ] no se lleva bien con table o no la estoy usando adecuadamente, porque tengo el error:

```
Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : 
  (converted from warning) cannot xtfrm data frames
```

Tres preguntas:

¿Alguna idea para usar table dentro de un loop?

¿Alguna aproximación diferente para asegurar que el mutate - case when no omita casos? (pensé en usar un TRUE ~ -99 dentro de los case_when pero tendría que validar manual las categorias que se perdieron y tener cuidado con los NA)

¿Por qué la función table no admite el operador [?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Por qué la función table no admite el operador [?

Lo admite perfectamente, pero dependiendo de tu entorno, puede ocurrir que `df$y` y `df[, "y"]` generen resultados diferentes. La segunda opción, según la versión de R o la configuración del entorno, puede retornar un vector o un `data.frame`. Para lograr los mismo resultados, es conveniente indicar explícitamente que si estamos seleccionando una sola columna, el retorno sea promovido a un objeto de menor nivel como un vector, caso contrario el retorno sería un `data.frame` de un sola columna:

```
> class(df2[, "y", drop = FALSE])
[1] "data.frame"
> class(df2[, "y", drop = TRUE])
[1] "integer"
```

El tema en tu caso, es que opción por defecto elije R, por lo que comentas pareciera que el valor por defecto es `drop = FALSE`, y claro, el comportamiento de `table()` en este caso variará del que estás esperando. No se que versión de R usas, en mi caso con la `4.1.3` obtengo un `warning`, en tu caso pareciera un `error`. De cualquier forma, para evitar este problema, podrías indicar explicitamente el retorno de un vector:

```
table(df1[, "y", drop=TRUE], df2[, "y", drop=TRUE])
```

> ¿Alguna idea para usar table dentro de un loop?

Si, algo como esto:

```
lista <- list()
for(i in colnames(df1)){
  lista[[i]] <- table(df1[, i, drop=TRUE], df2[, i, drop=TRUE])
}
lista

$x
             
              1 2
  categoria 1 3 0
  categoria 2 0 2

$y
   
    1 2
  A 3 0
  B 0 2
```

> ¿Alguna aproximación diferente para asegurar que el mutate - case when
> no omita casos?

El problema en tu caso es que el `case_when()` retorna un valor numérico, si fuera una cadena sería más fácil de ver los casos que no cumplen con las condciones:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(x == "categoria 1" ~ "1", 
                       x == "categoria 2" ~ "2",
                       is.na(x) ~ "NA",
                       TRUE ~ paste("Sin condicion:", x)
                       )
         )
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. La verdad no tenía idea del comportamiento de `df[, "y"]` al retornar un data.frame en ciertos casos. Mientras buscaba soluciones, googleé sobre las diferencias entre `df$x` y `df[, "y"]` pero no encontré demasiado detalle. Uso versión `4.2.0`, capaz hubo algún ajuste y ahora es un error en vez de warning.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Prueba lo siguiente:

```
# Crear una lista para guardar la información
  L <- list()
# Cambiar la i por valores numéricos
  for(i in 1:ncol(df1)){
    L[[i]] <- table(df1[, i], df2[, i])
  }
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
[[1]]
             
              1 2
  categoria 1 3 0
  categoria 2 0 2

[[2]]
   
    1 2
  A 3 0
  B 0 2
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es una solución válida. Sin embargo, puntúo la de @Patricio Moracho porque tiene una explicación más detallada sobre el error.